# Unable to correctly encrypt data using RSA/ECB/PKCS1 in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, cryptography, node-rsa

Im using the node-rsa package for encrypting data as follows

```
const crypto = require('crypto')
const NodeRSA = require('node-rsa')
const path = require("path")
const fs = require("fs")

const absolutePath = path.resolve('./public_key.pem')
const publicKey = fs.readFileSync(absolutePath, "utf8")

var key = new NodeRSA();
key.importKey(publicKey, 'pkcs8-public');
key.setOptions({environment: 'node', encryptionScheme: 'pkcs1'});
const result = key.encrypt('{"message": "hello"}', 'base64')
```

But now when i try to decrypt the result as follows:

```
key.decryptPublic(result, 'utf-8')
```

I get the following error message:

> Error: Error during decryption (probably incorrect key). Original
>   error: Error: error:0407008A:rsa
>   routines:RSA_padding_check_PKCS1_type_1:invalid padding
>       at NodeRSA.module.exports.NodeRSA.$$decryptKey (/home/runner/node_modules/node-rsa/src/NodeRSA.js:301:19)
>       at NodeRSA.module.exports.NodeRSA.decryptPublic (/home/runner/node_modules/node-rsa/src/NodeRSA.js:267:21)
>       at evalmachine.:16:17
>       at Script.runInContext (vm.js:133:20)
>       at Object.runInContext (vm.js:311:6)
>       at evaluate (/run_dir/repl.js:133:14)
>       at ReadStream. (/run_dir/repl.js:116:5)
>       at ReadStream.emit (events.js:198:13)
>       at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:288:12)
>       at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:269:11)

How can i fix this ?

Thanks.

Comment: I wrote an article about this once (I've forgotten everything I learned) and it might be helpful: [https://dev.to/subterrane/i-learned-enough-web-crypto-to-be-dangerous-5b5j](https://dev.to/subterrane/i-learned-enough-web-crypto-to-be-dangerous-5b5j)

Answer (score 0):

You're using the wrong key to decrypt.

You should use the private key.

```
key.decrypt(buffer, [encoding]);
```

Not the public key as you currently are:

```
key.decryptPublic(buffer, [encoding]); // use public key for decryption
```

RSA generally flows as, encrypt with public, decrypt with private.

Answer (score 0):

let encryptedText = encrypted.toString("base64");

and this how You decrypt it
let readPrivateKey = fs.readFileSync("./keys/private_key.txt", "utf-8");
let decrypted = privateDecrypt(readPrivateKey, decryptBuffer);

this is what solve the problem which the the encoding scheme for both encryption and decryption should be the same.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the public key to encrypt, you can't use it for decryption, due to how asymmetric encryption works.

The `crypto.privateDecrypt()` is used for decrypting the given data content by using a private key passed in the parameter that was previously encrypted using the corresponding public key with the `crypto.publicEncrypt()` method.

Also see [tutorialspoint - `crypto.privateDecrypt()` Method in Node.js](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/crypto-privatedecrypt-method-in-node-js)